# Make buttons 100% when text pushes it below image

Tags: html, css

This is a complicated one and I don't even know if it is possible with CSS only.

I have an image, a piece of text and two buttons. When the text is small, and doesnt grow below the image, I want the buttons to be the next to the image. But when the text is so large it needs to continue below the image I want the buttons to grow to 100% width.
Long story short, I want the buttons to be the same size as the text.

**This is the desired result for small text.**
[image]

**This is the desired result when the text grows**
[image]

**Is this possible to do with CSS only?**

I've created a codepen for my current setup (only small text).
http://bit.ly/1TwajIf

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible using only CSS.

Comment: It's actually possible using CSS only :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yemima/7/edit?html,css,output) (try changing the height of the .img or the width of the output)

Great question! this is actually possible using only css.

I made the image `float: left` then use flex box for the container of the buttons like

```
.fill{

  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.fill>*{

  flex-grow: 1;

}
```

[image]

check the demo for full detail

Comment: Nice solve! I love flexbox. @user2740744 -- read up on flexbox but understand that it's still pretty new and so expect some weirdness. Don't try to use it if you develop a site for someone using IE8. Also, you will need prefixes for even modern browser support. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Taylor thanks! Yeah, flexbox is always to the rescue, changed my life ever since Hahaha

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot!